# Changing bounty prize winner in short period of time after giving the prize to prevent mistakes

Tags: feature-request, bounties

I have started bounty for +500 reputation points. By mistake I awarded it to the wrong person. Both user names started with `Tony` and I confused them. I want to repair the situation because user `Tony Stark` solved my problem and gave my question a lot of attention in 9 days span and he truly **deserves** the +500. I would like to award him.

Bounty topic: [Determine correct connectionString for web publishing for ASP.NET-MVC application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256988/determine-correct-connectionstring-for-web-publishing-for-asp-net-mvc-applicatio/26262031?noredirect=1#comment41525089_26262031)

Could it be permitted to change bounty winner for instance for 5 minutes since awarding anyone? Also I kindly ask support to help me clean the mess.

Comment: What's done is done. The answer is good and I've +1'ed it, share it among your friends and in other networks and over time it might get lots of upvotes.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Then I wasted rep points for useless answer, because I wanted award the other answer.

Comment: I fear that's true, kind of like buying the wrong product in shop then not being able to return it for a refund.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Why moderator would not help to do the right thing and solve the situation? Even for stack exchange it is weird.

Comment: Nobody can reverse a bounty once it was already awarded, not even a developer. The only thing moderators can do is revoke a bounty while it's still active.

Answer (score 7):

Then what happens when someone says "I accidentally changed who I awarded the bounty to, how do I change it back?" Your best advice is **be more careful**. There's already a confirmation to make sure you *really* want to award it to that person, and informing you that it is irreversible. Once you click that Yes button, it's done.

In your situation, I can't imagine how you managed to do that. Sure they have similar names, but the other Tony's answer was much, much shorter and *very* distinguishable from the other answer based on content. You should have been able to easily tell the difference.

Implementing this feature is not worth the effort and would have an extremely small use case.